# Where does for<'r, 's> fn(&'r MyType<'s>) -> bool go in the `impl std::fmt::Debug` definition?

Tags: rust

I have this type:

```
struct Ctx;

type CmdHandler = fn(&mut Ctx) -> bool;

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Cmd {
    pub name: String,
    pub handler: CmdHandler,
}

impl Cmd {
    pub fn new(name: String, handler: CmdHandler) -> Cmd {
        Cmd { name, handler }
    }
}
```

It ends up throwing this error:

```
error[E0277]: `for<'r> fn(&'r mut Ctx) -> bool` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
 --> src/main.rs:8:5
  |
8 |     pub handler: CmdHandler,
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `for<'r> fn(&'r mut Ctx) -> bool` cannot be formatted using `:?` because it doesn't implement `std::fmt::Debug`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::fmt::Debug` is not implemented for `for<'r> fn(&'r mut Ctx) -> bool`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::fmt::Debug` for `&for<'r> fn(&'r mut Ctx) -> bool`
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `std::fmt::Debug`
```

I can't figure out how to implement this trait. The part that's tripping me up is the `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r mut lib::server::cmd::Ctx<'s>) -> bool`; I can't figure out where this goes in the `impl std::fmt::Debug` definition.

Answer (score 3):

Automatic derivation of a trait like `Debug` works by recursively delegating to the `Debug` implementation of each field. In this case, the field `CmdHandler` is an alias for a function pointer, which doesn't implement `Debug`, so you cannot automatically derive `Debug` for `Cmd` because its `handler` field doesn't implement `Debug`.

The way around this is to [manually implement `Debug`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html#examples). One possible implementation could be:

```
impl fmt::Debug for Cmd {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Cmd {{ name: {:?} }}", self.name)
    }
}
```

Which would print as: `Cmd { name: "Something" }`

As @logansfmyth pointed out, you could also use the [`f.debug_struct`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.debug_struct) method to build a [`DebugStruct`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.DebugStruct.html):

```
impl fmt::Debug for Cmd {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt.debug_struct("Cmd")
            .field("name", &self.name)
            .finish()
    }
}
```

In this case, this will print the same as above, except you can use pretty printing if you format it as `{:#?}` instead of `{:?}`.

Comment: Even better would be to use [`f.debug_struct`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html#method.debug_struct) so the user still gets the benefit of toggling pretty-printing and such. https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3e6abfe7a0109b06222dbd4e31fce897&version=stable&mode=debug

Comment: Good idea, will expand.